# Ubuntu server header timeout

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm running

```
Ubuntu Linux 12.04.1
Kernel and CPU Linux 3.2.0-30-generic on x86_64.
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz, 8 cores
```

I recently came across this problem. I'm using apache2/php latest and when I run

```
$url_headers = @get_headers($url);
```

Inside PHP it would normally take milliseconds to within a second to get the headers. Now recently it can take up to 15 seconds or even timeout.

It has worked great for over a year and recently started doing this. I'm not sure how to go about fixing it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You're fetching headers from a remote URL. What led you to believe it's _your_ problem and not _their_ problem?

Comment: My script is running slow. After remove bits of it I found it to be that line causing it.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I see what you said now it's any header from any URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's all sorts of things that could be causing this. What have you done to investigate?

Most likely it's a DNS or firewall issue. You could check this easily by capturing the packets using wireshark, tcpdump or similar when such a request is being processed (looking up the IP address of the URL before the test may prime the DNS cache).

But that presupposes that you know how to interpret the data.

Comment: No luck cleared the cache on DNS,firewall is fine.

Comment: It cleared it self up.